# How to bust cache on JavaScript file without adding a get parameter?

Tags: javascript, caching

I have a JavaScript file `main.js` which is embedded on third party websites which I don't have control over. It's a widget for the third parties to use to connect to my site and display data.

When I update main.js, I need to bust the cache somehow. However, I can't go for the classic way of adding a version number as I don't have access to the embeds. They all simply include main.js as a script tag.

How can I bust cache of a script without the use of a get parameter (ie: main.js?ver=12355)?

Answer (score 0):

You can't actively "bust a cache" from the server side. You need to configure the caching behaviour so the client will check for an updated version at appropriate intervals. You need to find the right balance between being up-to-date and not killing your server with constant requests (which is always the tradeoff with all caching).

If you disable caching altogether, the library will always be up-to-date, but the client will be slowed down because it has to download the file over and over and you may be putting significant strain on your server.

The other extreme is to let the client cache indefinitely, but then it may be out of date for quite a long time.

So you want to find the right balance, allowing the client to cache the file for *some time* and be okay with it being out of date for *some time*, but not too long. When the client then does ask your server again, you'll want to be able to respond with a "nothing's changed" response, so the client can keep the file it already has without downloading it again.

For all that, your server needs to set the right HTTP headers:

- `Cache-Control: public/private` to indicate whether public proxies (e.g. CDNs) may cache the file or only the client itself
- `Cache-Control: max-age=...` to control how long the client may cache the file
- `Expires: ...` as an alternative to the above, setting an *absolute* time when the file expires
- `ETag: ...` to identify the file by its contents (e.g. a hash of the file), so the client can include an `If-None-Match` request header to allow the server to respond with a `304 Not Modified` status
- `Last-Modified: ...` as alternative to the above, allowing a client to include an `If-Modified-Since` request header

MDN has a great article about all this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching

Comment: Very good summary. Just for thinking: As I understand the new way of actual brower development does not force caching as most important goal any more as the speed of downloading files it is not longer the big(gest) problem. The new browser technique is to wrap every page into a sandbox so fingerprintings based on cached files are not longer possible. So turning of the cache for a single js file should not lead to bigger problems ... But maybe it would be a good practice to cache the file for the whole visit and not downloading it when a visitor only is calling a new (sub-)page.

Comment: Whether switching off caching is a problem or not greatly depends on your setup. If you have a small server serving that file and many clients embedding it (as may be the case with embedding on 3rd party sites), then you may positively kill your server with too many requests. You're in essence creating your own DDoS attack. And you'll waste your client's bandwidth and perhaps loading time needlessly. The privacy concerns should be secondary here, and browsers will worry about that in their own way, you don't need to sacrifice caching for that.

Comment: Yes. I absolutly agree!!!! But in this case the third party script is obviously hosted on a server which is prepared to be loaded from different projects ... it seems just to prepare datas by something like an AJAX-API. My hubble personal opionin in THIS SPECIAL case: I really don't think that in THIS case the additional number of downloads should be a problem ... but INDEED: if it would be the own project server, the sources of the server should be asigned to the traffic and pageload of a project in every case!